# Javascript object is null or not object in IE

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have a form to which a checkbox is added by javascript, when the form is submitted it checks if the checkbox has been ticked or not. This works fine in Firefox or Chrome, but in IE7 or 8 it causes an error document.myform.mycheckbox.checked is null or not an object.

```
var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
checkbox.type = "checkbox";
checkbox.name = "mycheckbox";
checkbox.value= 291;
var div = document.getElementById("addcb");
div.appendChild(checkbox);
checkbox.checked = false;
```

In the form tag I have onSubmit="return CheckForm();", which works ok in Firefox or Chrome, but in IE7 or 8 it submits the form without checking the form or other form objects.

```
if (document.myform.mycheckbox.checked == false){
    errorMsg += "\n\tAgree \t- Please Click I Agree Checkbox";
}

//If there is aproblem with the form then display an error
if ((errorMsg != "") || (errorMsgLong != "")){
    msg = "_______________________________________________________________\n\n";
    msg += "The form has not been submitted because there are problem(s) with the form.\n";
    msg += "Please correct the problem(s) and re-submit the form.\n";
    msg += "_______________________________________________________________\n\n";
    msg += "The following field(s) need to be corrected: -\n";

    errorMsg += alert(msg + errorMsg + "\n" + errorMsgLong);
    return false;
}

return true;
```

I used the Developer tools to create a Brakpoint which reports the error:

```
document.myform.mycheckbox.checked is null or not an object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While creating it, give it an ID as well

```
checkbox.id = "mycheckbox";
```

and then to find it do a

```
if (document.getElementById("mycheckbox").checked == false)
```

Comment: Still returning is null or not an object and submitting the form in IE7/8

Comment: What about `document.getElementById("mycheckbox").getAttribute('checked')` ?

Comment: Although it now dosen't work for Firefox/Chrome, still I can always detect the browser and alter the code according.

Comment: @user2895984 yes, browser detection is one way, but this is strange, the last update should work universally across all browsers. Btw, if using jQuery is an option for you I suggest to use it - it takes care of all such cross-browser issues in a very nice way. A simple code like `$('#mycheckbox').attr('checked')` would work the same accross all browsers. It also greatly simplifies DOM elemenet creation

Comment: Yes, this I thought was strange too. Normally it's Firefox that is picky about form objects having an id when trying to access elements using javascript, whereas IE doesn't.

Anyway, it seems that:

    document.getElementById("mycheckbox").getAttribute('checked') == false

Works for IE7/8 and :

    document.getElementById("mycheckbox").checked == false

Works for Firefox/Chrome. I used a browser detect routinue to serve up the script for IE or Firefox.